# why is my http request in nodejs slower than my fetch in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch-api

I run the following fetch/http request directly from my script in the browser:

```
const t0 = performance.now();
fetch("https://api.example/something", {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(res=>res.json())
.then(res => {
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(t1 - t0);
});
```

The timer returns on average 240ms.

After that I tried doing it using node:

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 30;
https.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;

const performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;
const options = {
    hostname: "api.example",
    path: "/something",
    method: 'GET',
    forever: true, 
    pool: false,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        "Connection":"Keep-Alive"
    }
}
        
const t0 = performance.now();
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    res.on('data', d => {
        const t1 = performance.now();
        process.stdout.write(t1 - t0);
    })
})
```

This returns on average 325 ms, which is considerable slower.

It is crucial that the api request is as fast as possible, this is the most important thing. The api is third party and therefor out of my control.

- Why the performance difference?
- What can I do to make it faster?
- Is the request within nodejs or the fetch within browser expected to be the fastest?

Comment: Not sure I'd call 85ms _"considerably slower"_ but have you tried using `node-fetch` or any other HTTP library? FYI, `GET` requests do not have any request body and therefore do not require the `Content-type` header

Comment: Performance testing in any garbage collected system is tricky.  You first have to get the environment up and running, let any initialization stuff that may be happening in the background complete.  Make sure the GC has had its time to do anything it wants to after the initialization code has run.  Then, make multiple passes of your performance test and capture the results.  Sometimes, its also useful to make 10 passes with a 5-10 second pause (using `setTimeout()` so the system is fully idle) between each and see how consistent the results are.

Comment: FYI, your nodejs app is only timing until the first data packet arrives which will be fine if there is only one data packet, but would be misleading if the retrieved data was larger.  You may want to use a pre-built package such as `node-fetch` or `got` that retrieves the whole response for you.